# Navegar por el historial de un webview

Tags: android-studio, webview-android

Estoy siguiendo la documentación oficial para que cuando se presione en el botón atras en un webview, se cargue la pagina anterior pero me aparece el siguiente error

```
'onKeyDown' overrides nothing

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview?hl=es-419#NavigatingHistory

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       


        web.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient(){

        }
        web.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient(){

        }


        val setting: WebSettings = web.settings
        setting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        web.loadUrl(urlwebs)
        

    }
    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack()
            return true
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) //no me deja usar onKeyDown en esta linea
    }
```

Nota: Estoy en un fragmento no se si eso, es relevante en este caso

Comment: Te está diciendo que `onKeyDown` no está sobreescribiendo nada. Posiblemente te olvidaste de extender/implementar alguna clase/interfaz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar los métodos `canGoBack()` que valida si puedes regresar y `goBack()` para regresar al historial

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView

Pero en este caso no debes usar `onKeyDown()` debes crear un menú que tenga esta accion  y llame la función que controle la navegación:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus?hl=es-419

o usar el método `onBackPressed()` para que uses la tecla de regreso del dispositivo, ejemplo:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var myWebView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView)
        myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://es.stackoverflow.com/")
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        // Valida si puedes regresar.
        if (myWebView.canGoBack())
            myWebView.goBack()//regresa en el historial.
        else
            super.onBackPressed()
    }

}
```

Comment: Funciono, estaba colocándolo en el fragmento pero tenia que ponerlo en la activity.

Answer (score 0):

Si solo vas a manejar el onBackPressed puedes usar en tu fragmento

```
OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(
        true // default to enabled
    ) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            //TODO WHEN PRESSED
        }
    };

  requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(
        this, // LifecycleOwner
        callback);
```